# Custom object XML serialization whithout any xml tags

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, iserializable

I would like to create a custom serializable "string" class to handle the default string formatting without implement the logic in all of the modells.

I created a serializable class with implicit string operator

```
[Serializable]
public class FormattedString : ISerializable
{

    public static implicit operator FormattedString(string s)
    {
        return new FormattedString() { OriginalString = s };
    }

    public string OriginalString { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.OriginalString))
            this.OriginalString = String.Empty;

        this.OriginalString = OriginalString.Trim().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
        return this.OriginalString;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("string", this.ToString());
    }
}
```

My problem is the serialized object look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SomeXml>
  <Zip2>
    <OriginalString>2094</OriginalString>
  </Zip2>
</SomeXml>
```

instead of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SomeXml>
  <Zip2>2094</Zip2>
</SomeXml>
```

How can I serialize an object the way i want? Is this possible at all?

Comment: The example XML is wrong if I use the "info.AddValue("string", this.ToString());" method. In this case the  tag will be "<string>2094</string>"

Comment: 1) What serializer are you using?  [tag:xmlserializer] does not support `ISerializable`.  [tag:datacontractserializer] does.  2) Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that shows how you are generating that XML?